# Devas and their appearance

Tags: theravada

Far as i know Devas are born without parents so why are they in two genders?

If they have no biological need to reproduce what is the reason for two genders and if the Devas are born after doing many good and noble things in this world, how are their companions and concubines are born, are they residing in a world inhabited by other beings?

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference because I don't know much about devas myself, but- are you interested in a specific tradition's take on this, or all of them? If a specific one, adding in some applicable tags might help you to get a better answer.

Comment: Do you have any references from Buddhist texts for stating that they have two genders or whether they have concubines and children?

Comment: @ruben2020 they can't have children in deva realm.For the rest of your comment, yes there is a whole sutra/sutta called "Vimana vattu" dedicated to explain it.   You can find a sermon about it here    http://mahamevnawa.lk/inenglish/dhamma-talks/                               Thank you for the comment  :)

Answer (score 3):

Reproduction is not the only function of having opposite genders. If that is the case, both males and females should look the same when sexual organs are covered. Even at the beginning([Agganna sutta](http://www.urbandharma.org/pdf/AggannaSutta.pdf)) of man kind, reproduction happened as a result of beings who looked different getting attracted to the differences.

Companion nymphs are beings who get born in heavens due to less powerful karma. Their main duty is to entertain the Deva who owns them.

Comment: Your saying - "If that is the case, both males and females should look the same when sexual organs are covered." Other than some alternations of sizes we are actually alike.Sex is not the only thing that defines a body structure evolution plays a big part in this,making a body that can withstand the impacts of nature.Humans are very much alike when in comes to appearance between genders.We even share some unwanted parts (Google this - reason for male nipples).I value your opinion just wanted to add by perspective.